# Spring-boot War on Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm having errors during deployment with Spring-boot 2.1.2.RELEASE on 
WebLogic 12.2.1.2.0.

This is the stack trace:

```
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V from class com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule
at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule.<init>(JavaTimeModule.java:168)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:122)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.registerWellKnownModulesIfAvailable(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:760)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.configure(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:639)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:623)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:59)
at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:76)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.<init>(FormContentFilter.java:60)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter.<init>(OrderedFormContentFilter.java:29)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration.formContentFilter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:166)
```

I've tried adding this to the weblogic.xml:

```
  <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.*</wls:package-name>
      <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*</wls:package-name>
      <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
      <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.*</wls:package-name>
      <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.*</wls:package-name>
      <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.module.*</wls:package-name>
```

I've also tried using prefer-web-inf classes. The StdSerializer class is in the jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.8 jar, which theoretically shouldn't be an issue because welogic doesn't have Jackson included. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Keep only these packages in your weblogic.xml file, the others are unnecessary:

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>org.springframeworks.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

2) Include this in your pom.xml as per [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html), section 92.1:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This error happens because Spring Boot is trying to start a Tomcat container, causing classpath conflicts. Setting the dependency as provided will remove most of those, and including com.fasterxml.jackson.* in your weblogic.xml will take care of the remaining conflict.